# Provide the link to the question while editing it in Reopen queue

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, hyperlinks, vote-to-reopen

I came across a question in Reopen queue which was closed as a duplicate of another one. The user edited his question to argue why it wasn't a duplicate. I agreed with his argument and wanted to Reopen the question. However, the post wasn't properly formatted and it needed to be edited for better presentation. So, I pressed **Edit and Reopen**.

But when I enter the editing mode - I just don't have access to any link which would help me take to that question which I am presently editing (remember I am in a review queue) or the user who asked it or the duplicate target or anything.... See for yourself:

> [image: reopen queue]

I had already edited the post substantially and I wanted to insert the link to that duplicate question so that it becomes clear that the user has seen it and is not satisfied with the answers given there... But I had encountered a complete deadlock.

So, once I enter the edit mode in Reopen queue, please provide the link to the question which I am editing, so that I can open it in a new tab if required.

Answer (score 2):

If you are editing and reopening, then you are asserting that it is not a duplicate question, and the "duplicate" link should not be included in the question.

After you're done editing, you can insert a comment below the question with the "related" link.

Comment: The intention to insert the duplicate link is to indicate that "I have seen this question already, and the answers provided there doesn't apply in my case because of such and such reasons"... It generally makes sure that once it gets reopened and the comments get cleaned up, someone doesn't come again and vote to close it once again - a preventive action basically... Even then, this feature-request is widely applicable - we just don't have any link to access the question - we might want to view the answers already provided or we may need it for whatever reason...